# Updating core from 8.2 to 8.3 via composer

Tags: 8, updating, composer

I am trying to update Drupal core to 8.3 but am running into difficulties.

At the bottom of the page is the composer.json file I am starting with.

If i change  "drupal/core": "~8.2" =>  "drupal/core": "~8.3" and then run `composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies` I get the following issues which i am not sure how to resolve this as they are not contained in the composer.json file i have included below.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.



   Problem 1
    - drupal/core 8.3.0 requires symfony/psr-http-message-bridge ^1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[1.0.x-dev].
    - drupal/core 8.3.x-dev requires symfony/psr-http-message-bridge ^1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[1.0.x-dev].
    - drupal/core 8.4.x-dev requires symfony/psr-http-message-bridge ^1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[1.0.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/psr-http-message-bridge 1.0.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 8.3.0-rc2
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 8.3.0-rc1
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 8.3.0-beta1
    - Installation request for symfony/psr-http-message-bridge v0.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[v0.2].
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/dom-crawler v3.2.6
    - Installation request for drupal/core ~8.3 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.3.0, 8.3.0-alpha1, 8.3.0-beta1, 8.3.0-rc1, 8.3.0-rc2, 8.3.x-dev, 8.4.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/dom-crawler v3.2.6
    - drupal/core 8.3.0-alpha1 requires symfony/dom-crawler >=2.8.13 <3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/dom-crawler[2.8.x-dev, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/dom-crawler[2.8.x-dev, v3.2.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/dom-crawler[v2.8.13, v3.2.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/dom-crawler[v2.8.14, v3.2.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/dom-crawler[v2.8.15, v3.2.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/dom-crawler[v2.8.16, v3.2.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/dom-crawler[v2.8.17, v3.2.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/dom-crawler[v2.8.18, v3.2.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/dom-crawler[v2.8.19, v3.2.6].
    - Installation request for symfony/dom-crawler (locked at v3.2.6) -> satisfiable by symfony/dom-crawler[v3.2.6].
```

original composer.json

```
{
"name": "drupal/drupal",
"description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
"type": "project",
"license": "GPL-2.0+",
"require": {
    "drupal/core": "~8.2",
    "drupal/backup_migrate": "4.x-dev",
    "composer/installers": "^1.0.21",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "~1.3",
    "drupal/console": "^1.0",
    "drupal/file_browser": "^1.0@alpha",
    "enyo/dropzone": "4.2.0",
    "desandro/masonry": "3.3.1",
    "desandro/imagesloaded": "3.1.8",
    "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^1.18",
    "drupal/ctools": "^3.0@alpha",
    "drupal/devel": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/migrate_tools": "^3.0",
    "drupal/migrate_plus": "^3.0",
    "drupal/media_entity": "^1.6",
    "drupal/media_entity_document": "^1.1",
    "drupal/media_entity_image": "^1.2",
    "drupal/inline_entity_form": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/entity_embed": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/entity_browser": "^1.0@beta",
    "paquettg/php-html-parser": "^1.7",
    "drupal/better_exposed_filters": "^3.0@alpha",
    "drupal/workbench_access": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/webform": "^5.0@beta",
    "j7mbo/twitter-api-php": "^1.0",
    "nesbot/carbon": "^1.22",
    "Drupal/userprotect": "^1.0",
    "drupal/config_ignore": "^1.2",
    "Drupal/permissions_by_term": "^1.16",
    "Drupal/views_menu_children_filter": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/sitemap": "^1.2",
    "drupal/xmlsitemap": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/simple_sitemap": "^2.8",
    "drupal/redirect": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/metatag": "^1.0",
    "drupal/acl": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/examples": "1.x-dev",
    "drupal/honeypot": "^1.23",
    "drupal/field_collection": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/dropzonejs": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/embed": "^1.0@RC",
    "drupal/pathauto": "^1.0@RC",
    "drupal/rabbit_hole": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/entity_reference_display": "^1.0",
    "drupal/field_group": "^1.0@RC",
    "drupal/layouter": "^1.0",
    "drupal/mailsystem": "^4.1",
    "drupal/mimemail": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/permissions_by_term": "^1.17",
    "drupal/content_access": "1.x-dev",
    "drupal/rules": "^3.0@alpha",
    "drupal/smart_trim": "^1.0",
    "drupal/taxonomy_menu": "^3.3",
    "drupal/token": "^1.0@RC",
    "drupal/typed_data": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/video_embed_field": "^1.4",
    "drupal/views_infinite_scroll": "^1.3",
    "drupal/noreferrer": "^1.1",
    "drupal/system_status": "^2.4",
    "drupal/google_analytics": "^2.1"
},
"replace": {

},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "autoloader-suffix": "Drupal8"
},
"extra": {
    "_readme": [
        "By default Drupal loads the autoloader from ./vendor/autoload.php.",
        "To change the autoloader you can edit ./autoload.php."
    ],
    "merge-plugin": {
        "include": [
            "core/composer.json"
        ],
        "recurse": false,
        "replace": false,
        "merge-extra": false
    },
    "installer-paths": {
        "modules/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-module"
        ],
        "modules/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-module"
        ],
        "libraries/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-library"
        ],
        "profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-profile"
        ],
        "themes/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-theme"
        ],
        "themes/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-theme"
        ]
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\": "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Composer"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "pre-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::preAutoloadDump",
    "post-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::ensureHtaccess",
    "post-package-install": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
    "post-package-update": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup"
},
"dependencies": {
    "backupmigrate/core": "dev-master",
    "psr/log": "dev-master"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url":  "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    },
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "desandro/masonry",
            "version": "3.3.1",
            "type": "drupal-library",
            "dist": {
                "url": "https://github.com/desandro/masonry/archive/v3.3.1.zip",
                "type": "zip"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "desandro/imagesloaded",
            "version": "3.1.8",
            "type": "drupal-library",
            "dist": {
                "url": "https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/archive/v3.1.8.zip",
                "type": "zip"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "enyo/dropzone",
            "version": "4.2.0",
            "type": "drupal-library",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/enyo/dropzone",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "origin/master"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/backupmigrate/backup_migrate_core"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: I ran into this last week, and fixed it, but am not 100% sure what I did was proper (I also use webflo/drupal-core-strict).  I would like to see a definitive answer about this.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @rreiss I had to delete .lock.  This is what worked for me:

```
rm -rf vendor && rm -rf docroot/core && rm -rf docroot/modules/contrib && rm -f composer.lock

composer require drupal/core:8.3.1 --update-with-dependencies
```

line one could be unique to your project, confirm by looking up installer-paths in your composer.json.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this same thing. To fix I backed-up/deleted the /vendor directory and ran 'composer update' again so Composer would re-download all dependencies.
I think installed dependencies vs. required get out of sync.

Comment: This is how I end up fixing similar Composer issues. I find it a frustrating 'solution' because it feels like a hack. If the purpose of Composer is to manage my dependencies then I kind of DO expect Composer to handle this kind of thing. As it is (with this 'fix'), Composer seems more like a tool to INSTALL my Drupal dependencies. Again this feels like a long winded hack because this is supposed to be an improvement over the 'download the new zip and overwrite the existing Drupal install' method.

Comment: I've experienced the same issue and I also had to delete composer.lock ..
https://www.drupal.org/node/2836351#comment-12056279

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue when attempting to upgrade from 8.3.7 to 8.4.0. I think I found the culprit.

In the DOCROOT composer.json file, I see the following lines:

```
"merge-plugin": {
    "include": [
        "core/composer.json"
    ],
    "recurse": false,
    "replace": false,
    "merge-extra": false
},
```

So this directs the DOCROOT composer.json file to refer to the `core/composer.json`file and also require those dependencies. The problem is that it is looking at the dependencies from your *currently installed version* of Drupal, whereas the upgraded version has new dependencies. This creates the conflict we're seeing.

Here is the solution I found which works. It does *not* require deleting any files or modules.

1)Download a copy of the `core/composer.json` file from *the tarball of the version of Drupal you are upgrading to*.

2)In your current installation, *replace* the `core/composer.json` file with the new version you just downloaded.

3)Update your DOCROOT composer.json file with "drupal/core:~8.x.x"(whatever you're upgrading to).

4)Run `composer update --with-dependencies` as usual. This time, the update should proceed. Then apply database/entity updates, rebuild the cache, etc. etc.

I'm a Windows user and definitely more of a site builder, so I won't even try to post command-line prompts to do these things in Linux. And I'm not sure if this is a "proper" solution, or even why that above code blocks the upgrade, but this is what worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Just noting that this seemed to work for me for core update from 8.2.3 > 8.3.7.
Note my Drupal 8 install used this:  https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold  which has this directory structure:

.git
.gitignore
composer.json
composer.lock
config
scripts
vendor
web

- Put site into maintenance mode: /admin/config/development/maintenance
- Run this command in the root of the site: `rm -rf vendor && rm -rf web/core && rm -f composer.lock`
- Run this command in the root of the site: `composer require drupal/core:8.3.7 --update-with-dependencies`
- Go to /update.php (or `drush updb`) and run the updates. It will say there are 17 to run. It will probably return errors, if so, go to /update.php and run updates again (this time it will say there are less to run). Go to home page when it is done.
- Check over the site.
- Take site out of maintenance mode: /admin/config/development/maintenance